# iOS app showing old app icon even after change

Tags: ios, xcode

I am changing app icon for my app and had below issue.

Even though I changed app icon still at times when I quit the app the animation shows old app icon and then transforms to new app icon. And also in Siri suggestion I still see old app icon. Will this be there even after app release or is it just a issue with running through Xcode. Is there anyway I can remove this app icon caching? I tried deleting old app and restarting device and then installing new app that solves this issue, but actual users won’t be doing this. Can anyone suggest any solution for this issue?

I am using Xcode 11 and I am on iOS 13.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clean build and delete derived data, and that should take care of your issue.  But users downloading app from App Store will not experience this issue.

1) `Product > Clean build folder`

2) `XCode > Preferences > Locations > click on arrow for derived data`

Answer (score 3):

The iOS Springboard caches the app icon. So as soon as you change the app icon it won’t reflect in Siri suggestions and few app quit animation may still show old app icon. Gradually as user starts using the app with new logo and when iOS springboard caches the app icon again it will start showing the new app icon. So, don’t worry gradually all your users will start seeing the new app icon.

Comment: any official link/documentation for this?

Comment: I noticed my app icon updating after longpressing the home screen which causes all apps to wiggle around. Exiting this state caused the update to happen on the second time (or maybe first time, but didn't notice it then).